# Is there an option or work around to convert excel to txt with no tabs

Tags: excel, txt

Looking for a way to convert a excel file into a txt file but does not tab out the data. I was looking this up and did not find much besides others adding it to notepad++ and other programs to get the tab character and replace/removing it all with nothing.

So if someone has found something more seamlessly for a user that would be great if not I guess I will have to teach some users how to work with notepad++ lol

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit hacky, but add a second sheet to the spreadsheet. Assuming the first sheet is the standard `Sheet1`, in A1, put the function `=CONCAT(Sheet1!1:1)`. Copy that down as many rows as needed to get everything from `Sheet1`, then save `Sheet2` as `.txt`. As everything's in one column, the tabs aren't included.